# python цикли for range мешают друг друга

Tags: python, django

есть несколько разных циклов если применить 3 то отлично работает но если 4 подряд то все повторяется
надо что эти цикли вообще отдельно работали не мешая друг друга
проверка полей на бд тоже не работает

```
for ja in range(1, 32):
    n = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 30, 31]
    dataja = date(ThisYear, 1, ja)
    print(' user -> ', ja)
    bdja = Gnahatakan.objects.filter(data=dataja, ararka=ararka, user=user).exists()
    jd = Gnahatakan.objects.create(
    dnox=request.user, 
    user=user, data=dataja, 
    ocenka=ocenka, ararka=ararka)
    if bdja:
        print('break january')
        print('**********')
        continue
        print('break january')
        print('**********')

for feb in range(1, 29):
    fe = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 28]
    datafeb = date(ThisYear, 2, feb)
    print(' user -> ', feb)
    bdfeb = Gnahatakan.objects.filter(data=datafeb, ararka=ararka, user=user).exists()
    fd = Gnahatakan.objects.create(
    dnox=request.user, 
    user=user, data=datafeb, 
    ocenka=ocenka, ararka=ararka)
    if bdfeb:
        print('break february')
        print('**********')
        continue
        print('break february')
        print('**********')


for march in range(1, 32):
    ma = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 30, 31]
    datamarch = date(ThisYear, 3, march)
    print(' user -> ', march)
    bdmarch = Gnahatakan.objects.filter(data=datamarch, ararka=ararka, user=user).exists()
    md = Gnahatakan.objects.create(
    dnox=request.user, 
    user=user, data=datamarch, 
    ocenka=ocenka, ararka=ararka)
    if bdmarch:
        print('break march')
        print('**********')
        continue
        print('break march')
        print('**********')


for april in range(1, 31):
    ap = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 30, 31]
    dataapril = date(ThisYear, 4, april)
    print(' user -> ', april)
    bdapril = Gnahatakan.objects.filter(data=dataapril, ararka=ararka, user=user).exists()
    ochange = Gnahatakan.objects.create(
    dnox=request.user, 
    user=user, data=dataapril, 
    ocenka=ocenka, ararka=ararka)

    if bdapril:
        continue
```

Comment: А с чего вы взяли, что они мешают друг другу?

Comment: ну объекты создаются по несколько раз

Comment: надо все 12 месяцев создавать объект 1 день 1 объект

Comment: А с чего вы взяли, что виноваты циклы. Виноват ваш код. Почему вы не проверяете на существование записей в БД? Или почему в БД не сделали уникальный составной ключ?

Comment: не могу. может поможите ?

Comment: как проверять существование в бд ?